# Automatically open a terminal window and run a command, robustly

Tags: terminal, applescript

I am looking for a way to automatically open a new window of Terminal.app and run a command in it.

I used to do this with AppleScript, in a way similar to this:

```
tell application "Terminal"
  do script ("some-command")
end tell
```

The official distribution of [Julia](https://julialang.org/) opens terminal windows in the same way.

However, if Terminal.app is set up to run a command on startup (which is an often recommended practical way to set a new shell without changing the login shell globally), this method simply fails.

Is there a robust method that works even when an alternative shell is used?

[image]

Comment: Why wouldn’t you change your log in shell, rather than use the command overload? I believe my answer should work either way, so I’ll assume you have some good reason to choose this.

Comment: @bmike I used this method because it was recommended by MacPorts: https://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/bash-completion I was wary of changing the login shell to something that may be removed or break (e.g. a failed upgrade). I don't know what would happen then.

Answer (score 2):

Save whatever script you wish to a file and when you change the extension to .command

Finder will robustly make a command line window that’s new to run that command / script. This works for whatever `#!/bin/whatever` shell or script you start the text file.

AppleScript can open documents just like when Finder clicks on them to open, this should be a fairly universal way to accomplish your task.

Comment: The file also has to be made executed, otherwise one will get the error e.g.:  "The file “filename.command” could not be executed because you do not have appropriate access privileges."

Comment: @user3439894 Indeed. I should probably expand this a little with another edit

Comment: One missing piece was: to launch this `.command` file programmatically, one must use `open`. However, it still doesn't work if Terminal is set to run a command on startup. It suffers from the same issue as the AppleScript method I used before. Does it work for you?

Comment: Actually, it seems that the problem appears _only_ when I set Terminal to use MacPorts's bash (`/opt/local/bin/bash`) or MacPorts's zsh. If I set it to use something else, e.g. `/bin/zsh` or `/bin/ksh`, then everything works fine, even with the AppleScript solution.

Comment: Huzzah @Szabolcs - I’ve been on iOS away from macOS all weekend. I welcome a substantial edit to my answer or your making a clearer answer and selecting it if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late to the party, but I just met the same problem today. The solution is to add the shell you are using to `/etc/shells`. Then the AppleScript works as intended.